# Apply a specific class/id to current page on menu (PHP)

Tags: php, menu

I have a menu like this:

```
<div id="blahblah" style="blahblah">
<a href="http://domain.com/folder/biography"><img style="blahblah" src="blahblahblahblah"></a>
<a href="http://domain.com/folder/contacts"><img style="blahblah" src="blahblahblahblah"></a>
<a href="http://domain.com/folder/gallery"><img style="blahblah" src="blahblahblahblah"></a>
<a href="http://domain.com/folder/dontknow"><img style="blahblah" src="blahblahblahblah"></a>
</div>
```

I'd like to have something that automatically adds a class="current" to the page I'm currently in. Links (as you can see in the code above) are like domain.com/folder/biography or domain.com/folder/contacts, so without .php/.html, etc.

I tried with:

```
<div id="blahblah" style="blahblah">
<a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'biography')) echo 'class="current"';?> href="http://domain.com/folder/biography"><img style="blahblah" src="blahblahblahblah"></a>
<a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'contacts')) echo 'class="current"';?> href="http://domain.com/folder/contacts"><img style="blahblah" src="blahblahblahblah"></a>
...
...
</div>
```

But it doesn't work... the solution with strops seems viable, probably I'm doing it wrong.. :P

Comment: Remember that strpos will return the position, so if the name of the script is 'biography.php' and you search for 'biorgraphy', it will return 0 which will evaluate to false ... add `!== false` to your conditionals ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should:

1. check the result of `strpos()` with `!== false`.
2. Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` rather than `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.
3. Wrap the code inside a function.

Something like this:

```
<?php
function get_current($name) {
  if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $name) !== false)
    echo 'class="current"';
}
?>

<div id="blahblah" style="blahblah">
  <a <?php get_current('biography') ?> href="http://domain.com/folder/biography"><img style="blahblah" src="blahblahblahblah"></a>
  <a <?php get_current('contacts') ?> href="http://domain.com/folder/contacts"><img style="blahblah" src="blahblahblahblah"></a>
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Another question.. ;)
For one entry I have "sub-entries". Is there a way to have multiple pages that "provide" the current class for one entry? Something like:


          <a <?php get_current('page1|page2|page3') ?> href="http://domain.com/folder/biography"><img style="blahblah" src="blahblahblahblah"></a>

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but PHP supports function with multi arguments, e.g: `get_current('page1', 'page2', 'page3')`. See [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/func_get_args). I can give you detailed answer if you create a new question with the HTML code and explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Here you are :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886203/multiple-arguments-for-a-php-function

Answer (score 1):

if the position is 0, then it will evaluate to FALSE in PHP.  You should check the return value specifically, i.e. >= 0.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `strpos()`, you could try this:

```
<?php $current = basename($path, ".php"); ?>

<a href="blahblah"<?php if ($current == 'biographies') echo ' class="current"'; ?> />
```

`$current` is the name of the current file, without the `.php` extension.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! ;)
Unfortunately this doesn't work.. :(