# Multiple arguments for a PHP function

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Follow up from this:
[Apply a specific class/id to current page on menu (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884624/apply-a-specific-class-id-to-current-page-on-menu-php)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        <div id="bottoni" style="float:right;margin-top:30px;margin-right:30px">

            <?php
            // funzione per ottenere la class 'current' per la pagina che si sta visitando
            function get_current($name) {
                if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $name) !== false)
                    echo 'id="current"';
            }
            ?>

            <a <?php get_current('biografia') ?> href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>biografia/"><img style="width:120px;margin-right:25px" src="http://robertocavosi.com/beta/wp-content/themes/robertocavosi/images/bottone_robertocavosi.jpg"></a>
            <a <?php get_current('attore') ?> <?php get_current('regista') ?> <?php get_current('autore') ?> <?php get_current('riconoscimenti') ?> <?php get_current('pubblicazioni') ?> <?php get_current('insegnamento') ?> id="tooltipclick"><img style="width:120px;margin-right:25px;cursor:pointer" src="http://robertocavosi.com/beta/wp-content/themes/robertocavosi/images/bottone_curriculum.jpg"></a>
            <a <?php get_current('gallery') ?> href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>gallery/"><img style="width:120px;margin-right:25px;border:0" src="http://robertocavosi.com/beta/wp-content/themes/robertocavosi/images/bottone_gallery.jpg"></a>
            <a <?php get_current('itinera') ?> href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>itinera/"><img style="width:120px;margin-right:25px;border:0" src="http://robertocavosi.com/beta/wp-content/themes/robertocavosi/images/bottone_itinera.jpg"></a>
            <a <?php get_current('contatti') ?> href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>contatti/"><img style="width:120px;border:0" src="http://robertocavosi.com/beta/wp-content/themes/robertocavosi/images/bottone_contatti.jpg"></a>
        </div>
```

I'd like to specify in one "call" all these:

```
 <?php get_current('attore') ?> <?php get_current('regista') ?> <?php get_current('autore') ?> <?php get_current('riconoscimenti') ?> <?php get_current('pubblicazioni') ?> <?php get_current('insegnamento') ?>
```

I tried with:

```
 <?php get_current('attore', 'regista', 'autore', 'riconoscimenti', 'pubblicazioni', 'insegnamento') ?>
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `func_get_args()` like this:

```
<?php
function get_current() {
  foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $arg) !== false)
      echo 'id="current"';
  }
}
```

Then you can call the function from HTML:

```
<a <?php get_current('attore', 'regista', 'autore') ?> id="tooltipclick"><img src="http://robertocavosi.com/beta/wp-content/themes/robertocavosi/images/bottone_curriculum.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect to just pass a function multiple arguments and have it work if the function is designed to accept multiple arguments.

Instead, put your arguments in an array and call the function in a loop:

```
<?php
$args = array('attore', 'regista', 'autore', 'riconoscimenti', 'pubblicazioni', 'insegnamento');
foreach ($args as $arg) { get_current($arg); }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
<?php
// funzione per ottenere la class 'current' per la pagina che si sta visitando
function get_current() {
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $arg) !== false) {
            echo 'id="current"';
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```